# Automatically generate columns name in CTE using SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression

I am building a pivot query inside a CTE. I have a table `Table_1`:

```
Store      Week     xCount
-------    ----     ------
101        1        138
105        1        37
109        1        59
101        2        282
109        2        97
105        3        60
109        3        87
```

This is the query I used to pivot `Table_1`:

```
with CTE as 
(
    select 
        *
    from 
        (select 
             store, week, xCount
         from 
             table_1) src
    pivot
        (sum(xcount)
             for week in ([1], [2], [3])
    ) piv;
)
Select * 
From CTE
```

And this is the result I got:

```
| STORE |   1 |   2 |   3 |
+-------+-----+-----+-----+
|   101 | 138 | 282 | null|
|   105 |  37 | null|  60 |
|   109 |  59 |  97 |  87 |
```

The result is fine, but now there is one more WEEK added.

I want to develop a CTE with pivot query that will automatically generate distinct weeks and create a column on that basis.

I did some research and found a recursive CTE can be used to do this. I am new to recursive CTE, so please anyone can help me to solve this issue.

I also tried dynamic pivot query but CTE does not allow dynamic query.

Please help.

Comment: Seems yo me like you are looking for [dynamic pivot.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404348/sql-server-dynamic-pivot-query)

Comment: But dynamic pivot doesn't work inside CTE

Comment: Yes a dynamic pivot works in a CTE, as long as the entire query including the CTE is dynamic, which is the solution you need.

Comment: No, it won't work inside a cte (unless the cte itself is a part of the dynamic query). However, the only way to return a dynamic number of columns is to use dynamic SQL, so perhaps you should consider giving up the cte...

Comment: Can i use recursive CTE?

Comment: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2783/script-to-create-dynamic-pivot-queries-in-sql-server/

Comment: @SqlProgrammer , if any of the below solution worked then consider [Accepting Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) or add more info/comment to the question if anything is missing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> dynamic pivot doesn't work inside CTE

No, but a CTE works inside a dynamic query:

```
{assuming you have declared the variables used below}
SELECT @Cols = {query to get the column names in a comma-separated string}

SET @sql='
with CTE as 
(
    select 
        *
    from 
        (select 
             store, week, xCount
         from 
             table_1) src
    pivot
        (sum(xcount)
             for week in ('+@Cols+')
    ) piv;
)
Select * 
From CTE
'

EXEC (@sql)
```

> Can i use recursive CTE?

No this isn't an appropriate use-case for a recursive CTE.

Comment: But i want to use this CTE inside other code and i don't want to put every code inside dynamic query

Comment: @SqlProgrammer , Then can you add full scenario in your question?

Comment: You can only use a CTE with one query.   What other code are you thinking you can use it in?    Maybe you need a temporary table instead of a CTE.

Answer (score 1):

```sql
/* Variable to hold unique Week to be used in PIVOT clause */
DECLARE @Weeks  NVARCHAR(MAX) = N''
/* Extract unique Week names with pivot formattings */
SELECT @Weeks  = @Weeks  + ', [' + COALESCE(week, '') + ']'
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT week FROM table_1) DT
/* Remove first comma and space */
SELECT @Weeks = LTRIM(STUFF(@Weeks , 1, 1, ''))


/* Variable to hold t-sql query */
DECLARE @CTEStatement NVARCHAR(MAX) = N''
/* Generate dynamic PIVOT query here */
SET @CTEStatement=N'
;WITH CTE as 
( SELECT *
    FROM 
        (SELECT
             store
            ,week
            ,xCount
         FROM 
             table_1) SRC
    PIVOT
        (SUM(xcount)
             FOR week in ('+ @Weeks +')
    ) PIV;
)
SELECT * 
FROM CTE
'

EXEC (@CTEStatement)
```